# Moving cursor with two fingers on Windows like on Mac

Tags: windows, mac, touchpad

On mac, when I tap and hold the touchpad to select some text with one finger, and use my second finger to move the cursor, the cursor moves allowing me to lift and use my second finger to move the cursor repeatedly, while first fingers makes sure that the mouse is held clicked.

On windows, I can do the same thing with one finger, but when I try to use my second finger to move the cursor further, this doesn't work.

This limits me quite a bit.

I hope I explained this clearly.

Is there a way to achieve this behaviour on windows?